# Error with StimulSoft v2015.2 (StiMvcMobile)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

I use stimulsoft 2015 v.2 in my mvc app i use stimvcmobile for design report
and when i run my app with below code i recieve some error:

```
 <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    @Html.Stimulsoft().RenderMvcMobileDesignerScripts()
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcMobileDesigner(new StiMvcMobileDesignerOptions()
        {
            ActionGetReportTemplate = "GetReportTemplate",
            ActionGetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshot"

         })
    </div>
</body>
```

> error: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Stimulsoft.Report.MvcMobile.StiMvcHelper.StiMvcMobileDesigner(string)' has some invalid arguments

My Resharper suggest Add `.ToString()` to end of Helper and above error remove but report designer not work why??Please Help??
My Code:

```
 @Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcMobileDesigner(new StiMvcMobileDesignerOptions()
        {
            ActionGetReportTemplate = "GetReportTemplate",
            ActionGetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshot"

        }.ToString())
```

And error in browser Console is:`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a name of the component as the first parameter.

```
... StiMvcMobileDesigner("StiMvcMobileViewer1", new StiMvcMobileDesignerOptions()
```